# running API in python on localhost

Tags: json, python-2.7, api, localhost, anaconda

I need to POST a JSON from a client to a server. I have written two simple files as client and server to run them on localhost. Running the second program on http://127.0.0.1:5000/a, I have this output:
[
  {
    "origin_lat": 38.916228, 
    "origin_lon": -77.031576
  }
]
I want to have the same output using POST request by running the first program on http://127.0.0.1:5001/b. It doesn't run and gives me this error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

I am running them on Anaconda.

First program:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests
   data=[]
   data.append({"origin_lat":38.916228,"origin_lon":-77.031576})

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/b")
def home():
   res = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/a", json=data)    
   dictFromServer = res.json()
   return jsonify(dictFromServer)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(port=5001,threaded=True)
```

Second program:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/a")
def post_api_fun_single_time():
   data=[]
   data.append({"origin_lat":38.916228,"origin_lon":-77.031576})
   return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(port=5000,threaded=True)
```

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: I edited it with what I tried @ChrisJohnson

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. The problem was that I was looking to run it using the browser. It can work if we test it by "Advanced REST client".